# Unable to Build Docker Image with gradlew Command

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, gradlew

I am trying to build docker image having following command in Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:13-jdk-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app-build
ADD . .
RUN pwd
RUN ./gradlew console:build
RUN ls /app-build/console/build/libs/
```

It exit with following message

```
/bin/sh: ./gradlew: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./gradlew console:build' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to place your local directory path where your docker file is located and the path of your code repo in docker build command
`docker build -f /home/ubuntu/your_project_repo/Dockerfile  /home/ubuntu/your_project_repo/`

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what `openjdk:13-jdk-alpine` already has in its image, but if does not already contain a `./gradlew` executable file, you will need to double-check that the line `ADD . .` in your `Dockerfile` is actually copying in the file `./gradlew`.

Is `./gradlew` stored locally in the same path as your Dockerfile? `ADD . .` will take all the files in the path of your Dockerfile and copy it over into your custom image.

Another way to check to see if you are copying in the correct files is by building the image and then using a `docker exec` command to manually check to see what files are in your custom Docker image.

I would use the following command to do this: `docker exec -it <name_of_docker_image> bash`

Comment: Yes ./gradlew stored locally in the same path as where Dockerfile exist.

Comment: Did you check to see if it was actually being copied and was in the correct path inside your image?

Comment: actually problem is that image did not get created and exit with error message.